# What's the proper way to run a graphQL mutation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I'm working with GraphQL in rails and sending a mutation to create a User in Graphiql. I'm getting nothing but errors though.

I'm setting up the mutation types and logic in the following files. I'll just show my createUser mutation since that's the one I can't get past.

create_user.rb

```
class Mutations::User::CreateUser < Mutations::BaseMutation
    argument :attributes, Types::UserInputType, required: true
    field :user, Types::UserType, null: false
    field :errors, [String], null: false

    def resolve(attributes:)
        user = User.new(attributes.to_kwargs)
        if user.save
            {
                user: user,
                errors: []
            }
        else
            {
                user: nil,
                errors: user.errors.full_messages
            }
        end
    end
end
```

```
module Types
  class UserType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :fname, String, null: true
    field :lname, String, null: true
    field :email, String, null: true
    field :password, String, null: true
    field :dpsst, String, null: true
    field :reports, [Types::ReportType], null: true
    field :reports_count, Integer, null: true
    field :token, String, null: false

    def reports_count
      object.reports.size
    end

  end
end
```

user_input_type.rb

```
  description "Attributes to create a user."
  argument :fname, String,'Firstname of user', required: true
    argument :lname, String,'Lastname of user', required: true
    argument :email, String,'Email of user', required: true
    argument :password, String,'Password of user', required: true
    argument :passwordConfirmation, String, 'Password confirmation', required: true
    argument :dpsst, String,'dpsst number of user', required: false
end
```

mutation_type.rb

```
module Types
  class MutationType < Types::BaseObject
    # TODO: remove me
    # field :test_field, String, null: false,
    #   description: "An example field added by the generator"
    # def test_field
    #   "Hello World"
    # end
    field :create_user, mutation: Mutations::User::CreateUser

    field :login, mutation: Mutations::User::Login
    field :token_login, mutation: Mutations::User::TokenLogin
    field :logout, mutation: Mutations::User::Logout
    field :update_user, mutation: Mutations::User::UpdateUser
    field :reset_password, mutation: Mutations::User::ResetPassword
    field :send_reset_password_instructions, mutation: Mutations::User::SendResetPasswordInstructions
    field :unlock, mutation: Mutations::User::Unlock
    field :resend_unlock_instructions, mutation: Mutations::User::ResendUnlockInstructions
  end
end
```

Now Here's a couple of the mutation layouts I've tried below. I just don't know how to write them 100%! or potentially my graphiql is messed up, because I'm inserting mutations that should work according to the internet. I suspect it might have something to do with the to_kwargs method...

mutations:

```
mutation createUserMutation($userInput: CreateUserInput!){
  createUser(input: $userInput) {
    user {
      id
      fname
    }
  }
}
  "userInput": {
    "email":"test@gmail.com",
    "password": "password",
    "fname":"Jake",
    "lname":"Tester",
    "passwordConfirmation":"password",
    "dpsst":"75323",
  }
}
```

```
mutation createUserMutation($attributes: UserInput!){
  createUser(input: {attributes: $attributes}) {
    user {
      token
      id
      fname
      lname
    }
  }
}
{
  "attributes": {
    "email":"test@gmail.com",
    "password": "password",
    "fname":"Jake",
    "lname":"Tester",
    "passwordConfirmation":"password",
    "dpsst":"75323"
  }
}
```

With the most recent try, I'm receiving these errors:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "unknown attribute 'passwordConfirmation' for User.",
    "backtrace":...(I can post this if you need it)
```

Please teach me how to make the proper mutation calls, or at least point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: `Types::UserType` ?

Comment: UserType added above!

Comment: when removing passwordConfirmation, I get the error ``` "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable $attributes of type UserInput! was provided invalid value for passwordConfirmation (Expected value to not be null)",```

Comment: because defined in input type as required

Answer (score 0):

found the issue.

Due to devise needing the password confirmation, but my actual create user logic not needing it, I could delete that key before using the information to create a user. I fixed it with:

create_user.rb

```
class Mutations::User::CreateUser < Mutations::BaseMutation
    argument :attributes, Types::UserInputType, required: true
    field :user, Types::UserType, null: false
    field :errors, [String], null: false

    def resolve(attributes:)
        userAttributes = attributes.to_kwargs
        if userAttributes[:password] == userAttributes[:passwordConfirmation]
            userAttributes.delete(:passwordConfirmation)
        end
        user = User.new(userAttributes)
        # userAttributes.attributes.except
        if user.save
            {
                user: user,
                errors: []
            }
        else
            {
                user: nil,
                errors: user.errors.full_messages
            }
        end
    end
end
```